# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError within Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model that is only ever created within active admin. I have the following controller setup:

```
def index
@events = Event.all
end

def new
 @event = Event.new
end 

def create
@event = Event.new(event_params)
```

end

```
private 

def event_params
 params.require(:event).permit(:venue, :trainer_id, :description, :training_request_id, :title, :date)
end
end
```

My event model is:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one     :trainer, inverse_of: :events
 belongs_to  :training_request, inverse_of: :event

 delegate :module, to: :training_request
end
```

All the fields are there but I cant see why it is throwing this error.

Here is the output from the error:

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"H0sdhO3JsWBb8tYvFm52YvGsVvcnArigaVD+1r5HzL8=",
 "event"=>{"training_request_id"=>"3",
 "venue"=>"this is a venue",
"description"=>"this is a descripton",
"title"=>"event title",
"date(1i)"=>"2018",
"date(2i)"=>"3",
"date(3i)"=>"5",
"date(4i)"=>"05",
"date(5i)"=>"00",
"commit"=>"Create Event"}
```

Anyone got any ideas why this is happening?

Its worth mentioning that within rails console it saves fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing

```
  controller do
    def permitted_params
     params.permit event: [:venue, :trainer_id, :description, :training_request_id, :title, :date]
   end
  end
```

inside `ActiveAdmin.register Event do`